# When a cube equals a square

Tags: terminology, monoid, idempotents

An element $x$ of a monoid is called *idempotent* if $x^2 = x$.  Is there a word for an element $x$ such that $x^3=x^2$?  (Of course it follows that $x^2$ is idempotent.)

Comment: For $x^2$ to be idempotent, the condition is $x^4=(x^2)^{2}=x^2.$

Comment: @Mathmore Right, and if $x^3=x^2$, then $x^4 = x^3\cdot x = x^2 \cdot x = x^3 = x^2$.

Comment: I don't think there is a name; the condition looks too artificial, even though it is simple, well-defined, and different from both "_$x$ is idempotent_" and "_$x^2$ is idempotent_".

Comment: Then again, if we were talking about matrices, I would call it defective and degenerate.

Comment: What is this obsession with names for every irrelevant property? There are too many of them, you'd end up with names like Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch (yes, that's a real place name). Formulas were invented to get rid of such clumsiness.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm sorry you find this property to be irrelevant; for me it is quite relevant at the moment.  Definitions of words were invented to replace clumsiness like "element such that $x^2=x$" with "idempotent".

Comment: And how does that change the fact that there are only so many meaningful words with less than ten syllables? Of course, one could always invent something for personal use, like "3-futility" ("2-futility" would be the same as "idempotent").

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm sure you're aware that mathematicans invent new words all the time, and many of them go beyond "personal use".  My advisor was quite proud of inventing the word "operad", which is now used throughout homotopy theory and higher category theory.  Only three syllables.  And a cursory glance at an English dictionary should convince you that mathematicians are nowhere near in danger of exhausting that resource for naming concepts either.  I am not interested in continuing this conversation any further.

Comment: Idempotence is intimately linked with projection operations so they are given a name of their own in more abstract settings where no natural geometry exists to make the term projection meaningful. The relation $x^3=x^2$ has no obvious geometric interpretation and has not shown any particularly nice properties so it's maintained enough irrelevance to avoid a name. It's important to remember nomenclature is a fundamentally social endeavor as you have to convince a community to use a word in order to have it become standard.

Comment: For what it's worth, the boundary operator in topology has this property (see [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=306366)) and the oscillation of a function has this property (see [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=306367)).

Comment: Another example is the plus construction on presheaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there exist integers such that $x^i = x^{i+p}$. The minimal $i$ and $p$ with this property are called respectively the *index* and the *period* of $x$. If $p = 1$, $x$ is said to be *aperiodic*.
Thus an element satifying $x^2 = x^3$ is an aperiodic element of index $2$.

Comment: Thanks; can you give a reference?  In particular, the word "aperiodic" seems very weird here; to me an "aperiodic" thing is one that has *no* period.

Comment: @/mike-shulman See [Monogenic semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_semigroup) and [Aperiodic semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_semigroup).

Comment: Thanks!  This seems like probably the best answer I could reasonably hope for.

Comment: You're welcome.